# Populating text fields on a website from android without showing a WebView

Tags: java, android, html

Is there a way to put values into text fields on a webpage from android without loading/showing a WebView? For example, I have two strings and would like to populate two fields on a webpage, is there a way to do this "in the background" or in other words, not having to open a window that the user sees?
Thanks

**Update**

Found a solution with the help of Tango

This is in my OkHttpHandler class:

```
public class OkHttpHandler extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    String cardNumber, privNumber;

    public  OkHttpHandler(String cardNumber, String privNumber) {

        this.cardNumber = cardNumber;
        this.privNumber = privNumber;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

        RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
                //Change .add first parameter to the text field you want to populate
                .add("CardNbr", cardNumber)
                .add("CardPin", privNumber).build();
        Request request = new Request.Builder().url(strings[0])
                .post(formBody).build();

        try {
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            if (!response.isSuccessful())
                throw new IOException("Unexpected code "+ request.toString());
            return response.body().string();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

A snippet of my MainActivity Class and I print the response to the Log

```
    OkHttpHandler handler = new OkHttpHandler(items.get(0).getNumber(), items.get(0).getPrivNumber());
    String result = "";
    try {
        result = handler.execute("urlHere.com").get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.d("returned value", result);
```

Comment: Welcome.  Please visit the help center to discover how to ask a good question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/)

```
 final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

     RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
            .add("field to be filled", "content")
            .build();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("webpage url")
            .post(formBody)
            .build();

        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
```